xterm not working in mininet CLI when connecting to host
I have downloaded and turned on the Mininet VM, then connected to it vis SSH in PuTTY. In the session, the X11 forwarding was enabled, and the X display location is set to "localhost:0". I have created a custom topology with the filename lineartopology.py with the following code:
#!/usr/bin/python
from mininet.topo import Topo
from mininet.net import Mininet
from mininet.node import CPULimitedHost
from mininet.link import TCLink
from mininet.util import irange, dumpNodeConnections
from mininet.log import setLogLevel
from mininet.cli import CLI

class LinearTopo(Topo):
    "Linear topology of n switches, with one host per switch."

    def __init__(self, n=2, **opts):
        """Init.
        n: number of switches (and hosts)
        hconf: host configuration options
        lconf: link configuration options"""
        super(LinearTopo, self).__init__(**opts)
        self.n = n

        # Adding the switches and hosts
        for i in range(1, n+1):
            switch = self.addSwitch(f's{i}')
            host = self.addHost(f'h{i}')
            self.addLink(host, switch)
            if i > 1:
                self.addLink(f's{i-1}', switch)

def simpleTest():
    "Create and test a simple network"
    topo = LinearTopo(n=4)
    net = Mininet(topo)
    net.start()
    print("Dumping host connections")
    dumpNodeConnections(net.hosts)
    print("Testing network connectivity")
    net.pingAll()
    CLI(net)
    net.stop()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    setLogLevel('info')
    simpleTest()

Before I accessed the CLI, I ran the "xterm" command and the xterm display appears (the X Server used is Xming, and the display number is set to 0). When I typed the cmd "sudo python lineartopology.py", the topology was successfully created and it enters the CLI, however when I tried to connect to the xterm for the hosts meaning using the "xterm h1 h4" cmd, the Xming display doesn't appear anymore, even after I have set the "export DISPLAY=localhost:0" cmd outside of the Mininet CLI. Does anyone know what might be the cause of this? Appreciate any help that is provided, thank you :)
These are the steps I've taken to try to solve this:

run sudo apt-get install xterm. But it says that xterm is already the newest version

Add the DISPLAY=localhost:0 cmd line in the .bashrc file

run sudo mn -x

run sudo -E mn

sudo apt-get install xorg

xauth list $DISPLAY. When i entered this, nothing appeared


I've already spent over a day on this, but all did not work, as after applying these steps the Xming display still didn't appear for any of the hosts in the topology

Found the solution to this thanks to @wavebreaker's answer in this thread "X11 connection rejected because of wrong authentication in Mininet", which was to add the -E in the command line.
This is the command that I ran:
sudo -E python lineartopology.py

